# Group by year and month and get min value for a month, with the date

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, postgresql-9.5

This is what my table looks like

```
Column  |     Type     |
--------+--------------+
id      | integer      |
date    | date         |
open    | numeric(9,2) |
close   | numeric(9,2) |
low     | numeric(9,2) |
high    | numeric(9,2) |
```

I'd like to get the date of the lowest close value for a given month, for all the months.

This is what I've managed to get,

```
SELECT 
    temp_table.year, temp_table.month, MIN(close)
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            date_trunc('year', date) as year, date_trunc('month', date) as month, date, close 
        FROM
            sensex_sensex
        GROUP BY 
            year, month, date, close
        ORDER BY 
            year, month
    ) AS temp_table
GROUP BY
    temp_table.year, temp_table.month
ORDER BY
    temp_table.year DESC, temp_table.month DESC;
```

This gives me the year month and lowest close value.
But when I try to add the date I get all the rows instead of being grouped by year and month.
How do I go about getting the result as

```
Year | Month | Date of Lowest Close in a Month | Lowest Close in a Month
```

Also additionally,

I'd also like to be able to find the least 5 close values in a month with their dates, again grouped by year and month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=ee5b0cebb311e3d4cf5b47349c2fec56)

Using the [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) `MIN` selects the minimum value per frame (the month in your case).

```
SELECT
    extract('year' FROM mydate) as year,
    extract('month' FROM mydate) as month,
    mydate, close
FROM (
    SELECT
        mydate,
        close,
        MIN(close) OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('month', mydate)) as min_close
    FROM
        temp_table
) s
WHERE close = min_close
```

Instead of `MIN` you could use `ROW_NUMBER`. This helps you if want to select not only the one minimum but the two or five smallest numbers (n):

```
SELECT
    extract('year' FROM mydate) as year,
    extract('month' FROM mydate) as month,
    mydate, close
FROM (
    SELECT
        mydate,
        close,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('month', mydate) ORDER BY close) as rn
    FROM
        temp_table
) s
WHERE rn <= n              -- n is the number of values you get.
```

---

Do you really need separate columns for year and month which can be easily calculated from the date?

Comment: Expanded answer and fiddle for n least values

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed.

Yep, you are right, I don't separate columns for month and year when I just pull it from the date.

Answer (score 1):

use corelatted subquery

```
SELECT 
  date_trunc('year', date) as year, date_trunc('month', date) as month, date, close 
            FROM
                sensex_sensex t where t.close=( select min(close)
                                    from 
                                   sensex_sensex t1
  where   date_trunc('year', t1.date)=date_trunc('year', t.date)
    and
     date_trunc('month', t1.date)=date_trunc('month', t.date)
 )
```

Or use window function

```
with cte (   
    select  
         date_trunc('year', date) as year,
         date_trunc('month', date) as month, date, close,
         min (close) over ( order by date ) rn 
    FROM
         sensex_sensex
) select * from cte where cte.rn=1
```

Comment: I need the date of when the close was min for a month, this gives me the min date of the month

Answer (score 0):

You can use correlated subquery

```
     SELECT date_trunc('year', date) as year, date_trunc('month', date) as month, date, close 
     FROM sensex_sensex a where close in 
    (select min(close) from sensex_sensex b 
     where date_trunc('year', a.date)=date_trunc('year', b.date) 
     and date_trunc('month', a.date)=date_trunc('month', b.date))
```

OR you can window function row_number()

```
select * from
(
SELECT date_trunc('year', date) as year, date_trunc('month', date) as month, date, close,row_number() over(partition by date_trunc('year', date),date_trunc('month', date) order by close) as rn
         FROM sensex_sensex
)A where rn=1
```

Comment: ERROR:  schema "a" does not exist

Comment: @at14, Updated it - a typo mistake there

Comment: this works now. but it's kinda slow, took about 40 seconds to run. The table has only 9k rows. Any thoughts on making it faster?

Comment: You can use window function and give it a try @at14